# Gulp Sass with files in folders and subfolders

Tags: sass, gulp

I am not quite familiar with Gulp but need to use it for a project. my folder structure is like this

```
- project
-- src 
--- sass
---- css
----- ..many .sass files here
----- partials
------ ...many .sass files here
-- www
--- css
----- ....css files should go here (working)
------ partials 
------- ...subfolder files should go here (not working)
```

My attempt looks like this

```
var config = {
  sass: {
    src: [
      './src/sass/css/**/**.scss', './src/sass/css/partials/**/**.scss
    ],
    paths: [
      './src/scss'
    ]
  },
 }
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.sass.src).pipe(sass({
        paths: config.sass.paths.map(function(p){
                return path.resolve(__dirname, p);
        })
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(config.dest, 'css')));
});
```

What would be the right way of doing this? Do I need to separate sass tasks as the destination directories are different? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials

Comment: You have an error in this code.   Missing a single quote in the src.